# Is there another area similar to Waterfront in or around Vancouver, BC?

Tags: vancouver, alcohol, nightlife

Today I was at Waterfront in Vancouver. There you can walk around the harbor almost directly at the waterline and get some beer in one of the bars there. Is there something similar anywhere else in Vancouver? A place where you can stroll around the sea or creek and get some drinks?

Comment: Possibly in North Vancouver? Maybe some of the beach areas down along the way to UBC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure! Vancouver is famous for its seawall - the path running the whole way around, especially the downtown region.

So in addition to Waterfront, you can go closer to Stanley Park and hit Coal Harbour.  There are quite a few restaurants and bars down there, although sometimes quite pricey.

The path continues all the way around Stanley Park, and back on the West side of downtown.

Over the other side at English Bay there are more places right down by Burrard Bridge - better for brunch say, or early evening meals watching the sunset.

Yale Town by False Creek inlet has some, but they're set back a bit.  However on the south side of False Creek around Olympic Village, the sea wall continues right around to there as well, and you find places like Monk McQueen's - a seafood restaurant and bar, as well as one or two others there.

Further west along that part of the seawall you hit Granville Island, where there's a market, restaurants and bars, although it can be a little expensive.  Continue along and you'll find Kitsalano beach, with coffee shops, The Local bar/pub, and a couple of other little places close to the shore as well.

Answer (score 5):

Granville Island is the first place that comes to mind. It's not far from downtown (just across the Granville St. Bridge) and is right down on the water with lots of restaurants.